# standard normal law is rotation invariant

Tags: probability

Prove that the standard normal law is rotation invariant, i.e.,x≝ UX for any matrix unitary matrix U

i've no idea hoe to prove it, any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If an $n$-dimensional variable $X$ has PDF $(2\pi)^{-n/2}\exp(-\tfrac12x^Tx)$, $Y:=UX$ has PDF $(2\pi)^{-n/2}\exp(-\tfrac12(U^{-1}y)^T(U^{-1}y))$, because the Jacobian is $|\det U|=1$. But$$(U^{-1}y)^T(U^{-1}y)=y^TU^{-1T}U^{-1}y=y^TUU^{-1}y=y^Ty.$$